# Boundedness vs Convergence of $\sum 1/n^{s}$ for $\sigma>1$

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Showing following Riemann Zeta series converges for $\sigma>1$ is considered easy in many sources. Here $s=\sigma+it$.

$$\sum \frac{1}{n^s}$$

A previous post presents the following argument [[link]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215277/does-zeta-converge-for-complex-numbers-res1-where-imaginary-part-is-not-zero).

$$\left \vert \displaystyle \sum \dfrac1{n^s} \right \vert \leq \displaystyle \sum \left \vert \dfrac1{n^s} \right \vert = \displaystyle \sum \left \vert \dfrac1{n^{\sigma + it}} \right \vert = \displaystyle \sum \dfrac1{n^{\sigma}} \left \vert \dfrac1{n^{it}} \right \vert = \displaystyle \sum\dfrac1{n^{\sigma}}$$

That is,

$$\left \vert \sum \dfrac1{n^s} \right \vert \leq \sum\dfrac1{n^{\sigma}}$$

The argument is that since $\sum 1/n^{\sigma}$ converges for $\sigma>1$ (by comparison with integrals for example) so does $\sum 1/n^{s}$.

**Question:** Surely this argument only tells that $|\sum 1/n^{s}|$ is **bounded**, not necessarily **convergent**, for $\sigma>1$.

Comment: But you've proved $\sum |\frac{1}{n^s}| < \infty$ so your series is even absolutelly convergent.

Comment: $\sum \frac{1}{n^s} < \infty$ would only prove it's bounded, but $\sum \vert \frac{1}{n^s} \vert < \infty$ already proves (absolute) convergence

Comment: Absolute convergence implies convergence.

Comment: I still don't see it. I agree that $\sum |1/n^s|<\infty$ is convergent, but the argument shows that $|\sum 1/n^s|$ is $\leq$ a bound, a bound which happens to be the convergent limit of  $\sum |1/n^s|$. What am I missing?

Comment: For a complex sequence $(z_n)$ the convergence of $\sum |z_n|$ implies convergence of $\sum z_n$. It's rather basic fact that absolute convergence implies convergence. Due to completeness of $\mathbb C$ it's enough to show that $\sum_{j=1}^n z_j$ is a Cauchy-sequence, which follows directly from the triangle inequality, i.e $|\sum_{j=k}^m z_j| \le \sum_{j=k}^m |z_j|$ and the latter can be made arbitrary small due to convergence of $\sum |z_n|$.

Comment: @DominikKutek- thank you - that is incredibly helpful. Feel free to add this as an answer, which I'll mark as solved.

Comment: Wait - we don't actually need the triangle inequality then. We simply show that $\sum |1/n^s|$ converges and that implies $\sum 1/n^s$ converges in the same domain $\sigma>1$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the theorem that states that if a series converges absolutely, then it converges. If $\sum|a_n|$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges.

And to prove convergence of $\sum|a_n|$ it's enough to prove it's bounded since it's a series of positive reals.

Comment: thanks - does this mean there is no need for the triangle inequality because we won't need to show $|\sum 1/n^s| \leq \sum |1/n^s|$? Why is it in the linked proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215277/does-zeta-converge-for-complex-numbers-res1-where-imaginary-part-is-not-zero?

Comment: You are right, that inequality is not needed.